# Redis client-side cache (tracking) test

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-server, redisclient, clientcache

I'm testing Redis client-side caching using redis-cli.

Redis server version: 7.0.11

redis-cli version: 7.0.11

redis-cli 1 I started with the monitor command:

```
redis-cli monitor
```

In redis-cli 2 I run the snippet:

```
HELLO: 3
CLIENT TRACKING ON PREFIX test: BCAST NOLOOP;
SET test:1 "a"
GET test:1
GET test:1
```

In the redis-cli 1 (monitor) every get command is shown.

```
1687010819.444931 [0 127.0.0.1:56346] "CLIENT" "TRACKING" "ON" "PREFIX" "test:" "BCAST" "NOLOOP"
1687010843.136642 [0 127.0.0.1:56346] "SET" "test:1" "a"
1687010854.656921 [0 127.0.0.1:56346] "GET" "test:1"
1687010856.557103 [0 127.0.0.1:56346] "GET" "test:1"
```

**I wasn't expecting to see the second GET command on the monitor.** As I understand it, **the second get shouldn't call the server**, it should get the data from the **redis-cli local cache**.

Do I need to implement caching somehow?  Does redi-cli not implement it? The Redis client for Ruby(redis-5.0.6) has the same behaviour, with or without hiredis(hiredis-client-0.14.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement the local cache part at client side. Normally, a client library should implement it.

However, AFAIK, both `redis-cli` and `hiredis` do not implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/redis/rueidis

This client supports client-side caching.